# Profile doesn't include the com.apple.application-identifier and com.apple.developer.aps-environment entitlements

Tags: ios, macos, testflight

I updated to Big Sur and I keep getting this error when trying to upload a build archive to testflight:

Profile doesn't include the com.apple.application-identifier and com.apple.developer.aps-environment entitlements.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Are you using Xcode 11.5 or Xcode 12?  You can't use beta tools to upload builds.  Make sure you use a released version of Xcode

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I am using both Xcode 11.5 and 12, I experienced this on 11.5 but I managed to find a workaround.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've just had the same problem. This solution is shorter:

1. Archive your project on Xcode 11
2. Open Xcode 12 Organizer
3. Select your archive
4. Upload to Testflight using Xcode 12
5. Done!

That's it. It seems to be a bug with Big Sur.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem from Xcode 11.5 since Big Sur update. I just downloaded Xcode 12 (https://developer.apple.com/download/), uploaded from Xcode 12 beta (open window>organizer, it is here from your Xcode 11.5 archive) and it worked, it is now in my App Store connect page and I could submit it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't upload in Xcode 11.5, how am I then going to upload my Update?
When doing it in 11.5 I get this error and if I upload it via this method, after trying to submit it I get:
*This build is using a beta version of Xcode and can’t be submitted. Make sure you’re using the latest version of Xcode or the latest seed release found in  What’s New in App Store Connect.*